# Show values in dashboard by current date

Tags: mysql, vb.net

hi guys im new here and i want to show the appointments in currentdate in vb.net using mysql here is my code heres my code

```
cn.Open()
cm = New MySqlCommand("select count(*) from tblappointment where date=" & Date.Today & "", cn)
frmDashBoard.lblAppointment.Text = Format(CLng(cm.ExecuteScalar), "#,##0")
cn.Close()
```

Comment: **NEVER** use string concatenation like that to build your query!

Comment: You are only retrieving the Count. Is that all you want? Is there more than one persons appointments in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You would do it diirectly in mysql

```
cn.Open()
cm = New MySqlCommand("select count(*) from table1 where `date`= cur_date", cn)
frmDashBoard.lblAppointment.Text = Format(CLng(cm.ExecuteScalar), "#,##0")
cn.Close()
```

But for the future when you add variables to your code use placeholders for

```
dim name as string    
cnn.ConnectionString = "............"
cmd.Connection = cnn
cnn.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  Name, adress  from tblappointment WHERE ID= @id"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtIDInput.Text )
Dim reader  = cmd.ExecuteReader()
while reader.Read()
   name= reader(1).ToString()
End While
```